# Validar para no encimar evento en cierto rango de fechas

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, fullcalendar

Estoy trabajando con el desarrollo del módulo de eventos el cual consiste en dar de alta eventos en el sistema colocando el día del evento, hora de inicio del evento y hora término del evento.

**Ejemplo:** Si ya existe un evento dado de alta con los siguientes datos.

**Día evento:** 05 de junio del 2021

**Hora inicio:** 13:00:00

**Hora termino:** 18:00:00

Atributos de la tabla eventos id_evento 1

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y quiero dar de alta un nuevo evento ese mismo día, pero ya sea entre el rango de fechas.

**Validación 1:** 14:00:00 - 15:00:00 no debería de dejar porque ya existe uno.

**Validación 2:**  12:00:00 - 19:00:00 no debería de dejar porque ya existe uno.

**Validación 3:** 11:00:00 – 14:00:00 no debería de dejar porque el evento que ya existe inicia a las 13:00:00 (la fecha inicio del evento dado de alta quedo en medio del evento nuevo).

**Validación 4:** 17:00:00 – 20:00:00 no debería de dejar porque el evento que ya existe aún no termina (la fecha fin del evento dado de alta quedo en medio del evento nuevo).

Estoy intentando validar para no empalmar eventos, pero no lo logro ya que si agrego un evento como la validación 3 y 4 me lo agrega y el evento se empalma, la validación 1 y 2 la hago sin ningún problema.

Les comparto mi consulta que tengo donde lo que hago es hacer un select y después imprimo ese select, si el array está vacío es que no hay eventos, pero si trae datos es que si existen eventos, como les comento ya me quedo la validación 1 y 2 que es lo que está en la consulta, pero la validación 3 y 4 no me queda.

```
    $this->db_sqlserver->select('*');        
    $this->db_sqlserver->from('evento');
    $this->db_sqlserver->where('fecha_inicio >=', $data['evento']['fecha_inicio']);
    $this->db_sqlserver->where('fecha_fin <=', $data['evento']['fecha_fin']);
    $query1 = $this->db_sqlserver->get()->result();

    $this->db_sqlserver->select('*');        
    $this->db_sqlserver->from('evento');
    $this->db_sqlserver->where('fecha_inicio <=', $data['evento']['fecha_inicio']);
    $this->db_sqlserver->where('fecha_fin >=', $data['evento']['fecha_fin']);
    $query2 = $this->db_sqlserver->get()->result();

    $result = array_merge($query1, $query2, $query3);

    print_r($result);
```

Podrían darme ideas de como validaría el evento para no empalmarlos.

Saludos y espero que me puedan apoyar.

Comment: Has probado librerías como [full calendar](https://fullcalendar.io/) o [Scheduler](https://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxScheduler/)?

Comment: De echo si lo estoy haciendo con fullcalendar, el problema es que se empalman los eventos. Como lo valido con fullcalendar?